# Returning a completely new layout to same page in Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to set up a dash app which has 2 layers:

- 1st page has a couple of input forms, and based on these inputs - `app_layout`
- 2nd page - which has a different set of intputs (`layout_more_inputs`) which pop up depending on what 1st page input is.

I am trying to return `layout_more_inputs` from a callback but it doesn't work.

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H3('welcome to app'),html.Br(),
    dcc.Input(id='input-00-state', type='text', value='QQQ'),
    dcc.Input(id='input-01-state', type='text', value='MOVE'),
    html.Button(id='submit-button-state', n_clicks=0, children='Go!'),
    html.Div(id='output-state'),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph-with-slider'),
])

layout_more_inputs = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='input-10-state', type='number', value='0.11'),
    dcc.Input(id='input-11-state', type='number', value=0.12),
    html.Button(id='submit-button-state2', n_clicks=0, children='Go Go!'),
])

#front page - 0
@app.callback(
    Output('container', 'children'),
    Input('submit-button-state', 'n_clicks'),
    State('input-00-state', 'value'),
    State('input-01-state', 'value'),
)
def ask_for_more_inputs(n_clicks,asset_str,event_str):
    print("input summary:")
    print(n_clicks,asset_str,event_str)
    return layout_more_inputs #<<--DOES NOT WORK

#front page - 1
@app.callback(
    Output('graph-with-slider', 'figure'),
    Output('output-state', 'children'),
    Input('submit-button-state2', 'n_clicks'),
    State('input-10-state', 'value'),
    State('input-11-state', 'value'),
)
def more_inputs(n_clicks,input0,input1):
    d = {'x': [input0, input1], 'y': [input0, input1]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    filtered_df = df

    fig = px.scatter(filtered_df, x="x", y="y")
    fig.update_layout(transition_duration=500)
    return fig, u'''Button pressed {} times, 1 is "{}", and 2 is "{}"'''.format(n_clicks,state1,state2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% on what exactly is is you're attempting to deliver, but one options would be to use Dash's `dcc.Tabs` property.

I've started & laid the groundwork, sort of, for you:

```py
import sys

import dash
from dash import html
from dash import dcc
from dash import no_update
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

# app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app = JupyterDash()

layout = html.Div([
    html.H3('welcome to app'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Input(id='input-00-state', type='text', value='QQQ'),
    dcc.Input(id='input-01-state', type='text', value='MOVE'),
    html.Button(id='submit-button-state', n_clicks=0, children='Go!'),
    html.Div(id='output-state'),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph-with-slider'),
])

layout_more_inputs = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='input-10-state', type='number', value=0.11),
    dcc.Input(id='input-11-state', type='number', value=0.12),
    html.Button(id='submit-button-state2', n_clicks=0, children='Go Go!'),
])

tabs = [
    dcc.Tab(label="Front Page - 0", children=layout),
    dcc.Tab(label="Front Page - 1", children=layout_more_inputs)
]

multitab_layout = [dcc.Tabs(id="tabs", children=tabs)]

app.layout = html.Div(
    [html.Div(id="multitab_layout", children=multitab_layout)])

# front page - 0

@app.callback(
    Output('container', 'children'),
    Input('submit-button-state', 'n_clicks'),
    [State('input-00-state', 'value'),
    State('input-01-state', 'value')]
)
def ask_for_more_inputs(n_clicks, asset_str, event_str):
    print("input summary:")
    print(n_clicks, asset_str, event_str)
    return layout_more_inputs  # <<--DOES NOT WORK

# front page - 1


@app.callback([
    Output('graph-with-slider', 'figure'),
    Output('output-state', 'children')
], Input('submit-button-state', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('submit-button-state2', 'n_clicks'), [
    State('input-00-state', 'value'),
    State('input-01-state', 'value'),
    State('input-10-state', 'value'),
    State('input-11-state', 'value')
])
def more_inputs(n_clicks, n_cliks2, input0, input1, state0, state1, state10,
                state11):
    d = {'x': [input0, input1], 'y': [input0, input1]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    filtered_df = df

    fig = px.scatter(filtered_df, x="x", y="y")
    fig.update_layout(transition_duration=500)
    return fig, u'''Button pressed {} times, 1 is "{}", and 2 is "{}"'''.format(
        n_clicks, state1, state2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

using your provided code; but not entirely sure where exactly you'd want it to go from here. In terms of UI/EX behavior etc. Perhaps this may be enough of a clue to get you going as you need to...

Comment: What's the need for separate pages/tabs? That would help -- to explain that requirement

Comment: Thank you so much @john-collins !! I hadn't thought of tabs at all - they're a really good addition to the way the layout here is organised.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah tabs are pretty cool and easy to use. There are also though other components (e.g. `dcc.Location`) for creating an app with multiple URLs (i.e., pages) (and which don't necessarily refresh the page, actually, when switching b/t). Is my answer here acceptable or is there more you'd like from it?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is this:
- First input field determines which input cells to ask for - when user fills `input-01-state` - the rest of input variables vary depending on the value in `input-01-state`  (i.e set1 of additional input fields if value of `input-01-state`  is `X` and a different set of additional input fields if the `input-01-state`  is `Y`.

Comment: Hmm, could you perhaps organize into a new question; I'd be happy to take a look and that would I think be the proper way to go about this rather than in the comments. You may as well provide your whole program that would make it easiest to help you, and be sure to properly tag, give a good (i.e., unique + descriptive) title, and in general write the question as clearly as possible (to mitigate the risk of a moderator closing it! I've seen it happen quite a few times; fyi)

Comment: thank you for the advice! have deleted the comments and moved the follow up to a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738178/dash-app-nonexistent-object-error-after-declaring-validation-layout

Comment:  - I just managed to get to it today! check it out when you can, hopefully it all makes sense